# Get a random object from a list of percentages

Tags: java, random

I can't seem to find an effective way of choosing a random object by a percentage to each object.

Basically, I give the method a map of objects, and a chance of that object being picked. Preferably I want it so it can have has many decimals as the longest one has, but 1 decimal is fine too.

```
public static <T> T random(Map<T, Double> chances) {
    T toReturn = null;
    double rand = new Random().nextInt(1000) / 10.0D;

    // ???

    return toReturn;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your map can have more than one different with a matching criteria to your random val

Comment: What about duplicating items by percentage (or re-iterating) this way you will have fair distribution and you can call random against new list

Answer (score 2):

Basic strategy:

1. Calculate a random percentage Rand from 0% inclusive to 100 exclusive%
2. Iterate through the Map's entrySet
3. For each entry, if the Value is less than Rand, Return Key
4. Otherwise, add Value to Rand and continue

Answer (score 1):

If each object is mapped to a probability (which presumably add to 100) then you have no choice but to iterate through them:

```
public static <T> T getRandomItem(Map<T, Double> chances) {
    double chance = random.nextDouble() * 100.0;
    double cumulative = 0.0;
    for (T item: chances.keySet()) {
        cumulative += chances.get(item);
        if (chance < cumulative)
            return item;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("chances don't sum to 100");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called "Fitness proportionate selection" you cant find more information (and sample code) on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection).

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would have use a list with cumulative chances. Let's say that you have five objects with chances 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3. Then I would create a new array A with values A=[0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0], that is, A[n]=A[n-1]+p_n if n>0 and A[0]=p_0 where p_n is the likelihood for object n. Then you can create a random number r and find the highest element x in A such that A[x]>r, and x is the index for the object you want.

Pseudo:

```
cumulative_chances = [chances[0]]
for i=1 to chances.size()
    cumulative_chances.append(chances[i]+cumulative_chances[i-1])
r=random(0, cumulative_chances.last())
i=0
while cumulative_chances[i]<r
   i++
return i
```

Note that I assume that p_n>0 for all n. In case you want to set the probability for any item to exactly zero, you will have to modify this slightly.

If nothing in your applications is performance sensitive, you can do this calculation inside the function. In other cases, I'd precalculate it. Note that the pseudo code is not sensitive to normalization of the values. They don't need to add upp to 1 (or 100 if you want percentage), it works anyway.

Comment: @PatrickParker You're right. I flipped the operator from > to < now.

Comment: better. but what if r=0 and cumulative_chances[0]=0?

Comment: @PatrickParker Well, it's just pseudo code. I'll add a comment that I assume that p_n>0 for all n.

Answer (score 0):

I did what Patrick Parker told me to do, and this works perfect! Thanks a lot.

```
public static <T> T random(CustomMap<T, Double> map) {
    double rand = (double) new Random().nextInt(10000001) / 100000.0D;
    double total = 0.0D;

    for (T t : map.getKeys()) {
        double chance = map.get(t);
        total += chance;

        if (total >= rand) return t;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: There's a slight problem here. You could return an item that has a 0% chance. That's why I said to use "less than" not "less than or equal to"

Comment: Always double check your edge cases. In this code there are two main edge cases. a) items with a zero percent chance, b) items with a 100 percent chance

Comment: Yeah, even though I did around 10,000 tests without getting a single String with 0% chance, I removed the `=` now though, still works perfectly, thanks again for your help!

Comment: No that's still not right. Now you will have a problem at the other edge, where a weight of 100 would have a chance of not being selected.

Comment: Hint: change this number 10_000_001 to 10_000_000 in addition to removing the `=`